# How to wrap user functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-libraries, c++17, static-libraries

I have three functions that will be used in different classes in a project. The functions use (only read) common variables, but manipulate the input data in a different way than each other.

I am not sure how to wrap those functions. I practically don't want common read-only variables to be available to the user. I came up with two solutions:

1. C-Style header only approach. This solution lets user to see var0 and var1. Which I don't want. (Namespace approach also can't hide read-only variables AFAIK.)

```
#ifndef FUNC_H
#define FUNC_H
const int var0 = 30;
const int var1 = 75;

void func0(float input0)
{//manipulate input0//}

void func1(float input1)
{//manipulate input1//}

void func2(float input2)
{//manipulate input//}
#endif //FUNC_H
```

2. Class approach

```
#ifndef FUNC_H
#define FUNC_H

class Func
{
    public:
        static void func0(float input0);
        static void func1(float input1);
        static void func2(float input2);

    private:
        Func();
        static const int var0 = 30;
        static const int var1 = 75;
};

void Func::func0(float input0){}
void Func::func1(float input1){}
void Func::func2(float input2){}

#endif //FUNC_H
```

This works but I am not sure if this is the right way of accomplishing what I want. Basically, I want to wrap them similar to STL libraries. What do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have your functions in a header file (for example, as inline functions or templated functions), it is typical to use a `detail` namespace. Yes, users of your header can access it, but it is common practice to just ignore it (as it is an implementation detail)

So,

```
#ifndef FUNC_H
#define FUNC_H

namespace detail {
    const int var0 = 30;
    const int var1 = 75;
}

void func0(float input0)
{
    // Use `detail::var0`
}

void func1(float input1)
{
    using namespace detail;
    // Or put a using declaration and
    // just use `var0`

}

void func2(float input2)
{
    // ...
}
#endif //FUNC_H
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the common variables are part of the implementation, and not the interface, just put them in an implementation file, along with the function definitions.

So, the layout could be:

```
// func_h.hpp
#ifndef FUNC_H
#define FUNC_H

// only declarations
void func0(float input0);
void func1(float input1);
void func2(float input2);

#endif //FUNC_H
```

and

```
// func_h.cpp

// common variables not part of the interface
const int var0 = 30;
const int var1 = 75;

// but definitions can use the common variables

void func0(float input0)
{//manipulate input0//}

void func1(float input1)
{//manipulate input1//}

void func2(float input2)
{//manipulate input//}
```

Comment: As a more general question, is this the generic way of hiding algorithm-specific variables from the  user, placing them into `.cpp`files?

Comment: This is one way at least. It's also how you can hide implementation specific functions. From c++20 there will be modules, which will make this much cleaner.